# Henry's secret in The Time Traveler's Wife

Tags: plot-explanation, the-time-travelers-wife

In the movie The Time Traveler's Wife, shortly after Henry meets Clare for the first time, Clare spends the night at Henry's. Following morning she finds a lipstick in Henry's bathroom, and when Henry comes in he explains it by saying "I'm not doing that anymore/It's in the past" (something along those lines, not a direct quote).

In another scene he's dressed up as a drag queen. No explanation is given, and I haven't had the chance to read the book. So I'm wondering, what does it mean? Is/was he a transvestite?

Answer (score 10):

Henry does have a relationship with another woman named Ingrid in the book.  This takes place before he meets Clare.  Ingrid doesn't appear in the movie, but it's her lipstick that Clare finds in the book, so I assume it was hers as well in the film, but they just dropped the character due to time/budget constraints.

I've only seen the film once, but I don't remember a scene where Henry was dressed in drag.

Answer (score 7):

Henry dressed like a drag queen because he would steal clothes from the first store he came across every time, so that may be a reason.

The reason for that lipstick looks like it's from a previous relationship to another woman before meeting with Clare. This also becomes clear to me after `Bill the Lizard`'s answer.